# Remove white background on page load shows image in place of it

Tags: html, css

I have to remove white background on page load in place of it show 2_image.jpg and after that body image 1_image.jpg will be shown.Is it possible through css or may be script will be use. I have tried this but not working

```
<style>
body {
  background: url("../images/1_image.jpg") #070707; 
  background-color:#070707;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
.box {
    background:url("../images/2_image.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    top:0px;
}
</style>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add some punctuation to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample approach.

Create 2 Classes one is to make div hidden.

```
.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

Second one to show image.

```
.show_image{
position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) url(/img/spinner.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
z-index:100;
background-size: 5ex;
}
```

And your HTML code would be

```
<div class="show_image"></div>
<div class="hidden box"> Your actual content </div>
```

Initially your content will be hidden state and loading image will be displayed.

After completion of page loading just toggle the hidden class.

```
$('.box').removeClass("hidden");
$('.show_image').addClass("hidden");
```

So that your content will become visible and loading image will be hidden.

Let me know if you need to any help regarding Page Load.

Comment: I have to try this for body image not to take another div class

Comment: I hope your main intention is to show loading image while the page is loading. Isn't it ?

Comment: I have to show a full background image when page load not white background and after that body image will be shown

Comment: I have edited the show_image class,While the page is loading, image will be displayed at the middle of the page and the  entire page is in transparent background. So Whenever your page gets loaded, then add hidden class to that image div. Then your content will be displayed.